# Detecting and distinguishing keys in PyGame

Tags: python, pygame

```
    bg = "lv1.jpg"
    ch = "char.png"

    import pygame, sys
    from pygame.locals import *

    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 400), 0, 32)
    background = pygame.image.load(bg).convert()
    char = pygame.image.load(ch).convert_alpha()


    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    charspeed = 0

    charx = 100
    chary = 200

    running = True

    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                running = False
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type== KEYDOWN:
                if event.type == K_LEFT:
                    charspeed = -100
                elif event.type == K_RIGHT:
                    charspeed = +100

            if event.type== KEYUP:
                if event.key==K_LEFT:
                    charspeed=0
                elif event.key==K_RIGHT:
                    charspeed=0


        screen.blit(background, (0,0))


        milli = clock.tick()
        seconds = milli/1000.
        chardm = seconds*charspeed 
        charx += chardm

        screen.blit(char, (charx, chary))

        pygame.display.update()
```

For some reason the charspeed wont increment by 100 when i press down on the right key. I am trying to make a game with a clock but it doesn't seem to work. I am very new to pygame as you can see so Plz help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if event.type== KEYDOWN:
    if event.type == K_LEFT:
        charspeed = -100
    elif event.type == K_RIGHT:
        charspeed = +100
```

The `event.type` is `KEYDOWN`, so it can't also be `K_RIGHT`.

What you want is `event.key == K_RIGHT`.

See the [`pygame.event`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) docs for details.